# Header Origin not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, cordova

I want to bring a web application from PhoneGap to pc browser just because I need to do some tests. Inside the WebApp there are some XMLHttpRequest which fail because the Header origin is null.

I've already tried to run Chrome with this command :

```
chromium-browser index.html  --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I've got the same error :

```
Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I can't understand why with android emulator everything works properly. 
Also phonegap loads the local file :

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 1);
```

**More or less I've solved it with this add On for Firefox!**

It might be useful for others people :

[Firefox add-ons Force CORS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/)

Comment: I think it's because the demand must come from the same server to not break the "Same origin policy". Which is apparently your case.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try using this flag *--disable-web-security* when launching chromium. Obviously, it's for dev purposes only.

Comment: of course! I prefer developing in the browser with firebug or tools for chrome than using android emulator!